# Write a C daemon type program with an interactive command line interface in linux

Tags: c, linux

I have written a c program that runs in the background performing an ongoing function.  It works fine, but I want to get information out of it while it is running.
I used these instructions to make the program a daemon:
http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html
How do I modify the program C code so that it will accept a command line argument while it is already running?

Example:

`$ daemon_program` <-- start the daemon program, it is now running in the background.

`$ daemon_program --status` <-- type in the name of the daemon program with a parameter to have it type information to the terminal.

`$ Status is good` <-- daemon_program writes the status to the terminal

Is there a name for this type of setup?

Comment: having a daemon writing to stdout is a very bad idea as it will be in a race condition with any other program that is writing to the terminal.   Suggest writing to syslog.log instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your program would do something like this (pseudocode):

```
void main(string[] args) {

    if( args[1] == "-d" ) {

        namedPipe = createNamedPipe("mydaemon");
        startThread( doStuff );

        while( ReadCommandsFromNamedPipe( out command ) ) {
            ExecuteCommand( command );
        }
    }
    else {

        namedPipe = connectToExistingNamedPipe("mydaemon");
        if( namedPipe == null ) die("Daemon is not running");

        while( PromptUserForCommandFromStdIn( out cmd ) ) {
            sendCommandDownNamedPipe( cmd );
            readResponseFromNamedPipe();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
>./myDaemon -d
<< MyDaemon now running and listening for commands on named-pipe

> ./myDaemon
<< Please enter an interactive command
> get status
<< blargh
```

Comment: You may want to send a signal like SIGUSR1 to the daemon to alert it about upcoming interactive query (and handle the signal as appropriate in the daemon).